# How to show pointer after it has been hidden by unclutter

Tags: x11, bspwm, xcursor

I am automatically hiding the cursor with `unclutter -idle 3` in my bspwmrc. But I want the cursor to show again ever time I focus a different window with the keyboard. (This would provide a little more visual feedback as to which window focus was moved to).

bspwm has a setting that makes the cursor move to the newly focused window anytime you change focus with the keyboard. This setting is enabled for me, but it doesn't make a difference visually because the cursor is almost always hidden. Ideally, I would like to modify the keybindings I have to change focus so that they unhide the cursor before (or immediately after) changing focus, then three seconds later, unclutter would hide it again.

There doesn't seem to be an option to show the cursor once it has been hidden with unclutter, and googling around didn't produce any results. Is there a command that will show the cursor?

Comment: If you disable `unclutter`, does the mouse pointer tell you which window gained focus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try adding a second command to the `sxhkd` configuration lines that send `bspc` focus commands to move the mouse just a little after it, for example with `xdotool mousemove_relative 1 0`.

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm! One thing to note though, I decided to put this command _before_ the command that changes focus, not after. I guess one pixel doesn't make that much of a difference, but bspwm automatically centers the cursor on the newly focused node, and I disrupting that just didn't feel right, so I put it before.

Comment: Much better idea. I should have thought of it!

Answer (score 0):

Mouse pointer does not tell you which window has focus. Tell you window manager to style the focused window differently.

Comment: It already does. But when windows are on the edge of the screen it's hard to tell that the borders are different colors.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is one of the things that really annoys me about stack exchange - If you don't provide more information (like why you need the feature you're asking for), people give you a wrong solution because they don't know what you're really asking. But if you tell them why you want it, they give you a wrong solution because they think you should be doing it a different way. All I want is an answer to the question I asked, not a suggestion for how I should do it differently.

Comment: If you disable `unclutter`, does the mouse pointer tell you which window gained focus?

Comment: bspwm has a setting that makes the cursor move to the newly focused window anytime you change focus with the keyboard. This setting is enabled for me, but it doesn't make a difference visually because the cursor is almost always hidden. Ideally, I would like to modify the keybindings I have to change focus so that they unhide the cursor before (or immediately after) changing focus, then three seconds later, unclutter would hide it again.